# Do the trains in RDRII follow a specific schedule that I can use to plan a train robbery?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

So, I am attempting to do a train robbery, but I can't find a train at any of the places I usually look for them. I discovered that you can actually use pocket watches, and at this point I can't seem to find any real use for knowing the exact time, so I was wonderin if maybe the trains and stagecoaches follow a specific schedule. If they do, then I could just lie in wait at the perfect spot to jump on, and know exactly when a train will be passing by.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They do. I found a train timetable around the back of Riggs station. 11am to Saint Denis is getting robbed by me